# Looking for how to create a Generic CreateDataAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

to create a dataset such as

```
 System.Data.Common.DBConnection conn = getConn();
 DbCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();

 DbDataAdapter da = // get a datadapter from conn ??? There is NO CreateDataAdapter here ?
 da.SelectCommand = com;
 da.Fill(ds);
```

any help ?

UPDATE - I know there's no CreateDataAdapter() method there, looking for a workaround !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'am not sure if understand correctly.. but maybe you want something like this:

```
 using (System.Data.Common.DBConnection conn = getConn())
 {
  DbCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();
  DbDataAdapter da = CreateAdapter(com);
  // .. properties of adapter ..
  da.Fill(ds);
 }
```

EDIT (Not tested):

you can create generic CreateAdapter method like this (will create adapter based on command type):

```
private static DbDataAdapter CreateAdapter<T>(T a_command) where T: DbCommand
{
     if (a_command is SqlCommand)
     {
        return new SqlDataAdapter();
     }

     // .. others adapters..

     return null;
}
```

Comment: type maybe ?? "return new SqlCommand();" there's no CreateDataAdapter on Command or Connection, only on the ProviderFactory !

Comment: sorry it should be "new SqlDataAdapter()"

Answer (score 5):

New, in .NET Framework 4.5: [`GetFactory(DbConnection)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323136.aspx):

```
public static DbDataAdapter CreateDataAdapter(DbConnection connection)
{
   DbProviderFactory factory = null;
   factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connection);

   if (factory == null)
         throw new ArgumentException("Could not locate factory matching supplied DbConnection", "connection");

   return factory.CreateDataAdapter();
}
```

## See also

- [How to create a DbDataAdapter given a DbCommand or DbConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488962/how-to-create-a-dbdataadapter-given-a-dbcommand-or-dbconnection)

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflection:

```
        DbConnection conn = getConn();
        string assemblyName = conn.GetType().Assembly.FullName;
        string typeName = conn.GetType().FullName.Replace("Connection", "DataAdapter"); // You may be more conservative than this
        DbDataAdapter adapter = (DbDataAdapter)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName).Unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.aspx) under the remarks section it says that you need to implement the following constructors when using DbDataAdapter.

By the looks of it I think you should be inheriting from DbDataAdapter and not using it directly. Try using the [OledbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.aspx).

```
        OleDbConnection conn = getConn();
        OleDbCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
```